# strdist function stopped recognizing field reference in SOLR 5

Tags: solr

I remember in previous SOLR version (4.x) I was able to run the following query:

```
"(lastName:HILL)"
```

with fields

```
"*,score, strDistLastName:$lnamestrdist"
```

and with raw query params

```
"lnamestrdist=strdist('HILL',lastName,jw)"
```

This would give me result with an additional field which is result of strdist function using Jaro Winkler algorithm between a value and returned field.

For some reason in SOLR version 5.1 it always returns 0, even if strings match 1 to 1 (i.e. strdist should be 1).

I have checked it without using variables, i.e. only specifying fields as

```
"*,score, strdist('HILL',lastName,jw)"
```

but it also returns 0.

And only when I use another string literal like below, it returns 1:

```
"*,score, strdist('HILL','HILL',jw)"
```

I assume it means that strdist does not recognize fields anymore. Does anyone know why? Maybe syntax has changed or it's simply a bug?

Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 0):

My bad, I have "solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory" filter in index/query analyzers for the "lastNameExact" field, therefore value for strdist for 'HILL' and 'hill' was 0. After I corrected fields list to "*,score, strdist('hill',lastName,jw)", strdist became 1.

Sorry for the confusion :)